# How to use Groovy Eval.me with date variable

Tags: groovy, soapui

In soapUI groovy step I tried

```
log.info Eval.me('(new Date()).format("yyyy-MM-dd")')
```

It works fine.

But if I use variable `today` to store `new Date()` it does not work anymore why, what's the syntax instead of

```
def today = new Date()
log.info Eval.me('today.format("yyyy-MM-dd")')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def today = new Date ()
Eval.me('today', today, 'today.format("yyyy-MM-dd")')
```

[This](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#me(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) method is used.

Comment: Thanks. This implies I must know in advance what user will enter ?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Don't know the flow along with the scenario.

Comment: You must know in advance which named values you want to make available to the script. Eval makes the easy cases easy. To do more, use GroovyShell.